# Where is arc-elf32-gcc and how do i set it to PATH?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi3

I am new to RPI. I was following the steps to install the ARC GNU Toolchain in https://github.com/foss-for-synopsys-dwc-arc-processors/toolchain. i reached the step "Preparing Crosstool-NG". And after that, i do not know where to find arc-elf32-gcc and how to set it to my PATH. I have tried compiling a program for my Himax WE-I plus but it says "arc-elf32-gcc command not found" i have also looked for solutions online but to no avail. Can anyone please advise? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac or Linux computer, you can [download the ARC GNU Toolchain here](https://github.com/foss-for-synopsys-dwc-arc-processors/toolchain/releases) and add the `bin` directory within the extracted folder to your PATH, i.e.: `export PATH="~/arc_gnu_2020.09_prebuilt_elf32_le_linux_install/bin/:$PATH"`